# Is there any way to find 'metadata' on folders using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, directory-content

So I want to know if any of the folders in a directory have any subfolders or files in them, I tried just looking at the directory in PowerShell but it gave me only mode, last write time, and name. Is there any way of adding to this list to include metadata of the folder like size or number of subfiles/folders all I want to know is if they are empty or not so there may be a simpler way I'm missing.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: the `DirInfo` object that you get back from `Get-ChildItem` has a bunch of interesting properties and methods. the two that seem most likely to show what you want - any dirs OR any files - are `.GetDirectories()` and `.GetFiles()`.

Answer (score 4):

I see the question is tagged 'windows', so on Windows you could also use a COM object.

```
$fso = New-Object -ComObject Scripting.FileSystemObject

$folder = $fso.GetFolder($pathToFolder)
```

$folder will be an object with a bunch of interesting metadata on it, including SubFolders and Files. One of the interesting ones is Size. If Size is zero, there are no files in that directory, or in any nested subdirectories either.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to know if there are folders/subfolders and/or files then this will work:

```
$folder="C:\Test"

 Get-ChildItem $folder -Recurse | Measure-Object
```

Output (in my case)

```
Count    : 2
Average  :
Sum      :
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property :
```

If you want to see more properties then this might work for you:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Recurse   | Format-List *
```

alternatively you can also select the first x, last x, or even skip items:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Recurse |Select-Object -First 2| Format-List *
```

*-Recurse will check all folders below